# Awesomium, change useragent and referrer

Tags: c#, user-agent, referrer, awesomium

I just started to use awesomium.
I wanted to understand how to change user-agent and referrer.
i need for example to initialize 5 istance o awesomium webcontrol and for each of them i need different user-agent and different referrer.
this is my simple code

```
        private void newbrowser()
    {
            browser = new Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl();
            browser.Paint += browser_Paint;
            browser.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1, 1);
            browser.Name = "webControl";
            browser.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1024, 768);
            browser.Source = new System.Uri("https://www.google.com/", System.UriKind.Absolute);
            browser.TabIndex = 0;

    }

    void browser_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        browser.Paint -= browser_Paint;

        System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection myCol =
            new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
        myCol.Add("Referer", "http://www.yahoo.com");

        browser.SetHeaderDefinition("MyHeader", myCol);
        browser.AddHeaderRewriteRule("http://*", "MyHeader");
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        newbrowser();
    }
```

these 2 lines give an error

```
        browser.SetHeaderDefinition("MyHeader", myCol);
        browser.AddHeaderRewriteRule("http://*", "MyHeader");
```

> Error 1   'Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl' does not contain a
>   definition for 'SetHeaderDefinition'
>   Error 1   'Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl' does not contain a
>   definition for 'AddHeaderRewriteRule'

thanks for the help

Answer (score 7):

You need to set the user agent of the WebCore that governs your WebControl. This must be done before you create your WebControl.

```
public WebForm()
{
    if ( !WebCore.IsRunning )
        WebCore.Initialize( new WebConfig() { UserAgent = "YourUserAgent" } );

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution - is wrapper around WebBrowser, that implements IResourceInterceptor and can navigate with any additional headers:

```
public class class BrowserWrapper : IResourceInterceptor
{
    public BrowserWrapper()
    {
        WebCore.ResourceInterceptor = this;
        //BrowserWrapper can contains WebBrowser or knows how to delegate him Naviagtion (Source property)
    }

    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Uri, string> headers = new ConcurrentDictionary<Uri, string>();

    public void Navigate(Uri uri, string additionalHeaders = null)
    {
        if (additionalHeaders != null) headers.AddOrUpdate(uri, additionalHeaders, (url, h) => h);
        //Navigation to browser (WebControl.Source = uri...)
    }

    ResourceResponse IResourceInterceptor.OnRequest(ResourceRequest request)
    {
        string h;
        if (headers.TryRemove(request.Url, out h))
        {
            var hs = h.Split(':');
            request.AppendExtraHeader(hs[0], hs[1]);
        }
        return null;
    }

    bool IResourceInterceptor.OnFilterNavigation(NavigationRequest request)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```